# CSS 1em changing browser default line-height

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS file. With the `line-height: 1em;` property, the text looks like this:

[image]

and without that property it looks like this:

[image]

1em should be equal to what it already is, but if you look closely you can see that they are different. Why are these showing up differently?

```css
body {
  color: green;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Arial Black;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #ffcf79;
  font-size: 25px;      
}
h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 150%;
}
h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
p.para1 {color: blue;}
p.para2 {color: purple;}
p.para3 {
  color: purple;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background-color: #e5e4d7;
  padding: 20px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}
p.para4 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background-color: #e5e4d7;
  padding: 20px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 400px;       
}
.imagec {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: silver;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> The Fish Web Site </h1>
  <p class="para1"> Welcome to the Fish Web Site. Everything you want to know about fish is in this web site. </p>
  <img class="imagec" src="_images/barracuda.jpg">
  <h2> This is a section on Bass fish </h2>
  <p class="para2"> Bass fish live in lakes.  The word for fish in Latin is <i>Pisces</i>  </p>
  <p class="para3"> A fish is any member of a paraphyletic group of organisms that consist of all gill-bearing aquatic craniate animals that lack limbs with digits. Included in this definition are the living hagfish, lampreys, and cartilaginous and bony fish, as well as various extinct related groups. Most fish are ectothermic ("cold-blooded"), allowing their body temperatures to vary as ambient temperatures change, though some of the large active swimmers like white shark and tuna can hold a higher core temperature. Fish are abundant in most bodies of water. They can be found in nearly all aquatic environments, from high mountain streams (e.g., char and gudgeon) to the abyssal and even hadal depths of the deepest oceans (e.g., gulpers and anglerfish). At 32,000 species, fish exhibit greater species diversity than any other group of vertebrates.</p>
  <p class="para4"> A fish is any member of a paraphyletic group of organisms that consist of all gill-bearing aquatic craniate animals that lack limbs with digits. Included in this definition are the living hagfish, lampreys, and cartilaginous and bony fish, 
  as well as various extinct related groups. Most fish are ectothermic ("cold-blooded"), allowing their body temperatures to vary as ambient temperatures change, though some of the large active swimmers like white shark and tuna can hold a higher core temperature. Fish are abundant in most bodies of water. They can be found in nearly all aquatic environments, from high mountain streams (e.g., char and gudgeon) to the abyssal and even hadal depths of the deepest oceans (e.g., gulpers and anglerfish). At 32,000 species, fish exhibit greater species diversity than any other group of vertebrates.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: try looking at it with the DOM inspector highlighter tool, and see what the calculated height from the browser is.  It might be different

Comment: @marcellothearcane sorry, I'm a newbie to css. Can you please explain that?

Comment: sorry! assuming you're using chrome, press ctrl+shift+i to come up with the inspector.  in the top left of the new section, there should be a highlighting option when you hover your mouse over it.  If you click on the element, somewhere there's a 'computed' section, which you can look for things like margin, padding etc which would make a difference. (try setting them to 0 with `margin:0; padding: 0;` in your css too)

Comment: can you give us some code? try jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qd3tfo2u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason for browsers to have a default line-height of 1em, as in most cases no space between two lines would simply result in bad readability. Here is what I could find from official sources:

> Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's font-family. [[MDN/line-height]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Comment: Wait, but since em is a relative value, what is it being based off of?

Comment: It is based on the font-size. If you don't set a font-size then it is again the default value of that specific browser. If you set your font-size to 15px, then a line-height of 1em is equal to 15px and a line-height of 1.2em will result in 18px.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What does font-size entail? I know that sounds like a dumb question, but f and a are different heights and widths. Is the font size the maximum height?